# Stop Propagation did not work in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I'm trying to figure out how to use stop propagation method, when I clicked on the nested body element. First of all, I add click event to the body and to the element 'user-profile'. Then, when I clicked on this element, it triggered both click events, related to the element and body. And I want only element click event triggered, when the user clicked on it. So, what am I doing wrong?

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
            stopPropagation: function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        },
        componentDidMount: function() {
            var self = this;
            document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                self.setState({
                    isDropDown: false
                });
            });
        },
        render: function() {
            var className = cs('header-fixed', {'header-visible': this.props.visible});
            var userProfile = cs('user-profile', {'hide': !this.state.isDropDown });
            var userBox = cs('user-box', {'hide' : !this.state.isLogged});
            return (
                <header className={className}>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className={userBox}>
                        </div>
                        <div className={userProfile} onClick={this.stopPropagation}>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            );
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you clicking `userBox` or `userProfile` div?

Comment: @Davin Tryon I'm checking userProfile

Answer (score 0):

You can't control Vanila event listener in React.

`onClick={this.stopPropagation}` will work after body DOM get `click` event.

This is because...

1. Click occurs.
2. body element receives `click` event.
3. React recalculates the event and emit it again in React components.

---

So, this is my solution.

```
    module.exports = React.createClass({
                stopPropagation: function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            },
            componentDidMount: function() {
                var self = this;
                document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    self.setState({
                        isDropDown: false
                    });
                });
                React.findDOMNode(this.refs.userProfile).addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                  e.stopPropagation()
                })
            },
            render: function() {
                var className = cs('header-fixed', {'header-visible': this.props.visible});
                var userProfile = cs('user-profile', {'hide': !this.state.isDropDown });
                var userBox = cs('user-box', {'hide' : !this.state.isLogged});
                return (
                    <header className={className}>
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className={userBox}>
                            </div>
                            <div ref='userProfile' className={userProfile}>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                );
            }
        });
```

Have a nice day. :D

Comment: Additionally, you have to use `removeEventListener` in `componentWillUnmount ` if you are using vanila event listener.